# Shellscript 2nd newest folder in tgz

Tags: bash, shell, backup, tar

I've tried to develop a little backup shellscript.
When I Run it int the Backup_FILESERVER Folder it's creating the tgz.
But from /root I get an Error.

```
tar cvfz /NAS/for_tape/FILESERVER.tgz /NAS/Backup_FILESERVER/`ls -Art | tail -2 | head -n 1`
```

Error:

> tar: Tuesday: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
>
> tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

In the folder "/NAS/Backup_FILESERVER" are 5 folders for each weekday. Monday, Tuesday, ...

Is it possible to make it runable?

Comment: why don't you store the file name in a variable and feed it to tar command ??

Comment: I'm not very good in programming in bash. I thought to run this in one command line, it's more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
tar cvzf /NAS/for_tape/FILESERVER.tgz `find /NAS/Backup_FILESERVER/ -type d -exec sh -c "ls -1rt" \; | tail -2 | head -n 1`
```

`find` command with `ls -1rt` sorts the files based on the modification time and reverses it.

You can confirm if the command `find /NAS/Backup_FILESERVER/ -type d -exec sh -c "ls -1rt" \; | tail -2 | head -n 1` gives the folder you need before starting the compression

Comment: Thank you for your  suggestion, but when I run this command, nothing happens. I waited for about 5 minutes, but no archive was created.

Comment: @RickySpanish: `find /NAS/Backup_FILESERVER/ -type d -printf "%p\n" ` is not returning any folders? Are you sure the folder has contents?

Comment: no folder was returned. 
I'm pretty sure, there are 5 folders in this directory. :/  
Without the commands after the pipe, I get the content of the oldest folder.

Comment: @RickySpanish: Can you try just `-print` as `find /NAS/Backup_FILESERVER/ -type d -print"` without sort options. This should return the folders, else the folder you are searching for is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw your Answer. 
With this comment, I also get the content of the oldest folder. Maybe the content of all folders in /NAS/Backup_FILESERVER/

Comment: @RickySpanish: Accept the answer if it solves your problem, so that it can be made useful for others

Comment: unfortunately it didn't solve the problem, because I didn't get the content of the 2nd newest folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115405/discussion-between-inian-and-ricky-spanish).

Comment: @RickySpanish: try my latest update, if it doesn't work am taking down the answer